# jenkins build failure for Play sample database app deployment on Cloudbees

Tags: playframework, cloudbees

I am new to both Play and Cloudbees.  So far I am able to deploy the Hello World app.

But when I tried to deploy the "computer-database" sample Play 2.2 app to Cloudbees, Jenkins failed with the following console output:

```
Started by a push to CloudBees Forge 
Building remotely on s-bef1e580 in workspace /scratch/jenkins/workspace/computer-database
Checkout:computer-database / /scratch/jenkins/workspace/computer-database - hudson.remoting.Channel@342576ac:s-bef1e580
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 53a2fb1d645b80ac21e9645dbf8ccf9c5a48d377 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
Commencing build of Revision 6e8e5a4b23c43aabcc5eac843c3e51638e259cbe (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Checking out Revision 6e8e5a4b23c43aabcc5eac843c3e51638e259cbe (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
[computer-database] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8894784358670234242.sh
+ export DATABASE_URL_DB=na
+ DATABASE_URL_DB=na
+ export DATABASE_USERNAME_DB=na
+ DATABASE_USERNAME_DB=na
+ export DATABASE_PASSWORD_DB=na
+ DATABASE_PASSWORD_DB=na
+ ./sbt -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M -Dsbt.log.noformat=true clean compile test dist
[error] java.lang.NullPointerException
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results
[cloudbees-deployer] Skipping deployment as build result is FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I was able to run the app on localhost:9000 on my local machine (although it did give me a database evolution issue in the beginning which resolved itself when I clicked the "Run SQL Script" button).  Any help appreciated.

[UPDATE with full stacktrace below from my local machine]

```
    $ sbt -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dplay.version=2.2.0 clean compile test dist
[error] java.lang.NullPointerException
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? l
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sbt.StringUtilities$.nonEmpty(StringUtilities.scala:12)
    at sbt.impl.GroupArtifactID.$percent(DependencyBuilders.scala:50)
    at $e93cdeca4b09efb7ea54$.$sbtdef(/Users/jkwok/Personal/cloudbeesRepos/computer-database/project/plugins.sbt:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval$.getValue(Eval.scala:420)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$4.apply(Eval.scala:87)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$4.apply(Eval.scala:87)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSetting$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:82)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSetting$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:80)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:63)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:63)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$flatten$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:63)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:59)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$1.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:59)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:501)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:496)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:495)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:495)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:494)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:494)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Load$.loadSettings$1(Load.scala:494)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$expand$1(Load.scala:507)
    at sbt.Load$.loadSettings(Load.scala:511)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSbtFiles$1(Load.scala:465)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad$1(Load.scala:471)
    at sbt.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:474)
    at sbt.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:420)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:421)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:257)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:257)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:93)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:92)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:143)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:313)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:265)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:261)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:252)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:136)
    at sbt.Load$.buildPluginDefinition(Load.scala:593)
    at sbt.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:559)
    at sbt.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:547)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:411)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:257)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:257)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:93)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:92)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:143)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:313)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:265)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:261)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:252)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:136)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:40)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:434)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:428)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:428)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:95)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:176)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:87)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:80)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:69)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

Comment: Note the `Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here` warning. Maybe it's checking out the wrong revision? Check the revision number against your repository.

Comment: Going to be difficult without a full stack trace.  Did you try running it locally using the sbt command it's using?  Only thing I can think of offhand is that it won't run your evolutions in prod mode so you'll have to run them yourself.  Doesn't look like it's getting that far, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to bulid the project (both local and on cloudbee) after hardcoding the play version "2.2.0" into the plugins.sbt file.